# Matlab vs. Java

Tags: java, matlab, performance

How is MatLab slower than Java? Are there any ways in which it is faster?

Comment: Provide us more information please!

Answer (score 9):

Why do you ever want to compare these two at all? [Matlab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) is a numerical computing environment whereas Java is a object oriented language.

Answer (score 6):

<s>MatLab and Java are equally as fast to say. (Mat-Lab, Ja-va, both have 2 syllables)</s>
It has been pointed out in the comments that Java is faster to say even though both of the words have the same number of syllables.

Oh, you probably mean to compile.  MatLab is interpreted, so it's faster.

Oh, maybe you mean to execute...hell if I know...They are meant to be used for completely different things, I've never tested it.

**Clarification:**
Essentially what I am trying to say is that your question needs more context.  Most programming tasks would probably fit best in one or the other languages.  If your problem happens to be suitable for both, we need to know more about what you mean by fast.

Comment: Java's syllables are shorter, and there's a short silence between Mat and Lab out of respect for the rixoratory.

Comment: Technically speaking, Java is actually easier and faster to say - it is made up of two open syllables, whereas Matlab's are closed, hence the mouth has to make four distinct noises, as opposed to two. Just saying... :P

Comment: @jinguy you make me laugh :)
@Pete, what the hell is rixoratory? Google yields a single chinese document, from matlabedu.cn :D

Comment: @Pete, I was also not sure what you meant by that.

Answer (score 6):

I guess if you are writing an FFT from scratch Java will beat Matlab, however if you need to do fft's and use the Matlab provided libraries, Java will likely take a beating.

I guess you are trying to evaluate which environment to choose for a particular project. This is impossible to give advice on without a lot of background information.

If you will be doing a lot of low-level coding, calculations and data administration then probably Java will be better.

If you can decompose your problem in sequences of mathematical operations on blobs of data, (b e it vectors, matrices, tensors, ...) matlab will probably be a better fit.